# Problem with connecting Android Phone with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb, android

I have **Micromax Canvas Spark Q380** android phone . While connecting this phone via data cable with laptop with **edubuntu 14.04 LTS** OS , only charging of the phone is done. After connecting the phone , there is option where I able to choose to connect the phone as **Media Device** or **Camera** etc , but while I choose **Media Device** no action is done. I cannot read **Phone Memory** or **SD Card** by data cable . Is there any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.Ubuntu does not come with mtpfs installed.Open a terminal and type or paste "      sudo apt-get install mtpfs   ".  Now reboot and then connect your phone. 
Pieter

Comment: Using this command I install **mtpfs** , but still the problem is same

Comment: Okay then you have bigger problems. The next one is more involved and advanced. Go to   http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702  and read it until you understand it fully. Then do it. This must work for you.